# mongoose aggregate return an object with count if no documents found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query which works in a way that it search for bookings between two dates

```
const bookings = await Bookings.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          store: {
            $in: storeIds,
          },
          bookingDate: {
            $gte: new Date("2022-09-04"),
            $lte: new Date("2022-09-10"),
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$bookingDate",
          count: {
            $sum: 1,
          },
        },
      },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
    ]);
```

Result:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
```

But, there's a date 5 that doesn't contain any booking, what I want is if any date has no bookings and the object will generate containing a date as _id and a count of 0. Any solution for this?
So, my expected output is down below, Array[1] contains 2022-09-05 with count 0. Although I tried various methods to do so. But I got no success yet.. Please help me out

Expected output:

```
[
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-05T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-06T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "_id": "2022-09-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you add an example of your DB? Because I don't know if I don't understand or you want to output the values you are filtering using `$gte` and `$lte`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I updated the question with expected output.